# Migrate a QEMU/KVM VM from qemu:///system to qemu:///session

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virsh

I have a created a Windows 10 VM using `virt-manager` as user (not root).

However, when try to list the VMs with `virsh list --all`, My VM is not listed? And, if I specify the system URI with by running `virsh -c qemu:///system list --all`, I see my VM listed. 
I would like to migrate my VM from `qemu:///system` to `qemu:///session` to be able to list it with `virsh list --all`.

- How can I achieve that?

Comment: You lose a lot of functionality in the user session. Consider something like `alias virsh='virsh -c qemu:///system` instead.

Answer (score -2):

https://mike42.me/blog/libvirt-migrate-a-vm-from-qemusession-to-qemusystem

```
virsh undefine foo-machine
sudo virsh define foo-machine.xml 
sudo virsh start foo-machine
```

Comment: This is the opposite of what the poster asked for.