# `virsh -c qemu:///session list --all` lists VMs created in `QEMU/KVM` connection, but misses VM from `QEMU/KVM User session` of Virt-Manager

Tags: kvm-virtualization, libvirt, qemu, virsh

`# virsh -c qemu:///session list --all` lists only VMs created in `QEMU/KVM` connection (system !), but misses VM I've created in `QEMU/KVM User session` in GUI of Virt-Manager. Why? From below I unserstand I'm using correct syntax of the command:

[Migrate a QEMU/KVM VM from qemu:///system to qemu:///session](https://serverfault.com/questions/1068562/migrate-a-qemu-kvm-vm-from-qemu-system-to-qemu-session):

> when try to list the VMs with virsh list --all, My VM is not listed?
> And, if I specify the system URI with by running virsh -c
> qemu:///system list --all, I see my VM listed.

Using `virsh -c qemu:///system list --all` and `virsh list --all` produced same list.

[virt-manager doesn't show list of local KVMs but virsh does](https://serverfault.com/questions/418509/virt-manager-doesnt-show-list-of-local-kvms-but-virsh-does)

> Check the output of virsh uri. If it returns qemu:///session

Looks to me `virsh` can work with user session. Does it need some config for that?

[Virsh can't detect my new vm](https://serverfault.com/questions/981527/virsh-cant-detect-my-new-vm) talks about missing VM listed when running `virsh` w/out sudo, but I just get:

```
$ virsh uri
error: failed to connect to the hypervisor
```

Answer (score 0):

I understood (recalled) why `virsh` as ordinary user fails. I started virt-manager via `newgrp libvirt` trick from https://askubuntu.com/a/1119779/796396. Using it again in host console produces "correct" result:

```
$ newgrp libvirt
$ virsh --connect qemu:///session list --all
 Id   Name      State
------------------------
 1    LM_21_1   paused
```

So the issue of not listing VMs from `User session` was due to running `virsh` as root.

Why it listed `qemu:///system` ones instead? I guess for root `qemu:///session` = `qemu:///system`, correct?